# How to validate size of file uploads in Express with Multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, express, coffeescript

I'm using [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) as `multipart/form-data` middleware in [Express](http://expressjs.com/). I'm wondering how to validate the size of uploaded files, preferably while they're being uploaded.

I'm aware that you can set `limits` in the options object when instantiating Multer like so:

```coffee
app.use multer
  limits:
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024
```

However, this only truncates the uploaded files and doesn't allow to display an error message like "File is too big." when the file size exceeds the limit.

I also checked out the event handler `onFileUploadData(file, data)` in which you have access to the `file` object and the `data` buffer. Here I can check for the current file size by checking `data.length`. It's unclear to me, though, how to handle the case in which `data.length` is bigger than the maximal upload file size that I want to allow.

Ultimately, my idea is that when a request is parsed by Multer and the uploaded file is too big, I'd like to display a flash message to the user and redirect to the form, so she could try a smaller file. The `create` action of my controller looks something like this:

```coffee
exports.create = (req, res) ->
  Record.create(req.body)
  .success (record) ->
    image = req.files.image
    uploadImage(image, record.id).then ->
      req.flash 'success', 'Record created.'
      res.redirect "/records/#{record.id}"
  .error (err) ->
    req.flash 'error', err
    res.redirect 'records/new'
```

The problem is that `req.files.image` is already the parsed image which is uploaded to the systems tmp folder at this point. So even checking the file size here wouldn't really allow me to protect against unwanted large file uploads.

What's the best way to handle file upload validation in Express using Multer or other form-parsing middleware in general?

Answer (score 5):

To validate size of file uploads, you just have to use `req.file.buffer`

Below code is just a sample.

```js
// Set your file size limit

const maxSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; // for 1MB 

// validate file size

if (req.file.buffer.byteLength >= maxSize) {

// write code here

} else {

// write code here 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add a handler for `onFileUploadComplete` the `file` object is passed in which has a `truncated` property. If this property is set to `true`, that means that particular file exceeded the defined max file size limit.

EDIT: It seems although multer copies over the `truncated` property from busboy, it is using an old version of busboy that does not yet have the `truncated` property. There's an existing [issue](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/23) about updating the dependency. An alternative would be to tack on your own property to the `file` object passed to `onFileUploadData` when the max size is exceeded. This property should then be available on the `req.files.foo` object.

EDIT 2: It doesn't have the same "API" as multer or connect-multiparty (`req.files` and `req.body`), but I am working on [reformed](https://github.com/mscdex/reformed) which allows you to define validation rules and error messages. Like multer, it uses busboy under the hood.

Comment: Yeah, like I mentioned in my question, I know that I can do what you suggest even in the `onFileUploadData` handler. There I can check the data buffer and when `data.length < maxUploadSize` I know that the file size exceeds the max file size limit. That still doesn't help me with handling this situation. Since this handler is set in the options object on initialization of multer, I don't know about the `req` and `res` objects and don't see a way to do anything sensible with the fact that the file is too big at this stage.

Comment: You could tack on a property (e.g. `toobig`) to the `file` object in your `onFileUploadData` function that would then be visible in your route handler (e.g. `req.files.image.toobig`).